# NoMethodError in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I'm new at Ruby and I'm trying to make a method in my Project controller like so:

```
def update_phase
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    diff = (Date.current.year * 12 + Date.current.month) - (@project.starting.year * 12 + @project.starting.month)
    case 
        when diff >= 30
            @project.process = 11
            .
            .
            .
        when diff >= 0
            @project.process = 1
        else
            @project.process = 0
    end
    proc = @project.process.to_f
    case
        when proc >= 9 
            @project.phase = "Final"
        when proc >= 5
            @project.phase = "Desarrollo"
        when proc >= 1
            @project.phase = "Inicio"
        else
            @project.phase = "Error en el proceso"
    end
end
```

`starting` is a timestamp in the model. In my view I have:
`<% @project.update_phase %>`
but I get the error: `"NoMethodError in Projects#show"`
how can I fix this?

Comment: What's `starting`?

Comment: I tried doing that but neither the process nor the phase attribute are saved in the instance

Comment: starting is a timestamp in the Project model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what's or where does `starting` come from, you could use a `before_save` callback, this way everytime you're going to create a new record, it triggers the `update_phase` method and assigns the values for `process` and `phase` from the current project object:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :update_phase

  ...

  def update_phase
    diff = (Date.current.year * 12 + Date.current.month) - (self.starting.year * 12 + self.starting.month)
    case
      when diff >= 30
        self.process = 11
        ...
    end
    proc = self.process.to_f
    case
      when proc >= 9
        self.phase = 'Final'
        ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Oops, starting is an attribute from project I have updated both the question and my code and still have the same error, adding the line "before_save :update_phase" brings up the error "undefined method `before_save' for ProjectsController:Class Did you mean? before_filter" also the update_phase is called everytime the project is listed by the user so it will only run on already existing projects

Comment: You're using the method in the controller @IvanHid, it's a method on the class Project, that's why `before_save` isn't available.

Comment: Sorry I moved it to the controller because in the model it worked but it didn't update any of the attributes, it only displayed them for the page it was called

Comment: Thank you! after moving the method to the model it worked! turns out I was using @project instead of self